# Rounded Bottom Corners on Last HTML List Item?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, css

I have these dropdown menus that are functioning properly, except the bottom corners of the menu are not rounded.  I included the html, css & jquery code.  Would you know why my last list items aren't showing rounded bottom corners?

Thank you for your time!

HTML

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="Me" href="#">About Me</a>
        <li><a href="#">Favorite Films</a>
            <!-- Films Drop-Down Menu -->
            <ul>
                <li><a id="DC" href="#">DC Cinematic Universe</a></li>
                <li><a id="Bond" href="#">James Bond</a></li>
                <li><a id="Marvel" href="#">Marvel Cinematic Universe</a></li>
                <li><a id="ST" href="#">Star Trek</a></li>
                <li><a id="SW" href="#">Star Wars</a></li>
                <li><a id="X" href="#">X-Men</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /Films Drop-Down Menu -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Favorite TV Shows</a>
            <!-- TV Drop Down Menu -->
            <ul>
                <li><a id="Americans" href="#">Americans, The</a></li>
                <li><a id="GoT" href="#">Game of Thrones</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /TV Drop Down Menu -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
        nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(hsl(1,79%,30%), hsl(1, 88%, 44%), hsl(2,90%,26%));
    border: hsl(1,79%,30%) 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

nav li a {
    /* Makes entire block for link clickable - not just text. */
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    transform:skewX(160deg);
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFCC33;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: hsla(1,79%,30%,.8);
    /*Z-Index enables layering - higher values put elements toward top */
    z-index: 99;
}

nav li li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    /*border: 1px hsl(1,79%,30%);*/
}

nav li li a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Round bottom corners of menu items on bottom of drop-down menus.  */
nav li li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
    //DROP-DOWN MENUS
$('nav li').hover(function() {
    // stop() stops all animation before slideDown()
    $('ul',this).stop().slideDown(250);
},
    //When not hovering.
    function(){
        $('ul',this).stop().slideUp(250);
    }
);
//DROP-DOWN MENUS
```

Comment: You want the ul to have a border-radius? http://jsfiddle.net/q4NL3/

Comment: Then all 4 corners are rounded.  I only want the bottom corners rounded.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have is correct except for the selector for the last li. You need to do one of two things:

```
nav li ul:last-child {...bottom border radius code...}
```

Or...

```
nav li li:last-of-type {...}
```

This caught me off guard for a while as well and I'm not sure if the implementation changed at some point. `:last-child`, as the name indicates, selects the last child of a surrounding element, which is why you need to use it to specify the *parent* element.

`:last-of-type` selects the last of the specified element, `li` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the menu in a div and then declaring specifically last one of the list to be rounded ?

```
    divname li:last-of-type a
{
   border-bottom:thin solid black;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;    
}
```

Comment: last-of-type is definitely what you want over last-child. Last child would work if you declared it on the ul element rather than the li.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can make rounded corners different ways:

The first `10px` is top-left, 2° top-right, 3° bottom-right, 4° bottom-left:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

If you specify only one value, this will round all the corners:

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

Or individually:

```
border-top-left-radius:     10px;
border-top-right-radius:    10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:  10px;
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Based on my code, didn't I do it correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(hsl(1,79%,30%), hsl(1, 88%, 44%), hsl(2,90%,26%));
    border: hsl(1,79%,30%) 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

nav li a {
    /* Makes entire block for link clickable - not just text. */
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    transform:skewX(160deg);
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFCC33;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: hsla(1,79%,30%,.8);
    /*Z-Index enables layering - higher values put elements toward top */
    z-index: 99;
}

nav li li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    /*border: 1px hsl(1,79%,30%);*/
}

nav li li a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Round bottom corners of menu items on bottom of drop-down menus.  */
nav li li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background was applied to the nav ul ul while the border-radius was applied to the nav li li:last-child.  Moving the background to nav li li solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can change different corners of border-radius like this:

```
 .weee {
    border-radius: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em; /* top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left */
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/q4NL3/1/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, thats how I am trying to change the border-radius now: 
nav li li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

Comment: What did I do wrong to get down voted? The feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: I didnt downgrade you, but it may have been because my code already contained your suggestion.

Comment: If you read the full question, he didn't ask about how border radius works. He asked about how to round **the last** element of a list.

Comment: @Waymond Sure thing! Don't give up answering questions. Just make sure you have good grasp of the question or ask for clarification. Helps keep the quality of answers high and gains you some points along the way :)